# Why doesn't Esc-[ scroll left in `less`?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, escape-characters, less, scrolling, pager

According to the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lesskey) for `lesskey`,
the following keys are bound to left-scroll and right-scroll:

```
\e[       left-scroll
\e]       right-scroll
\e(       left-scroll
\e)       right-scroll
\kl       left-scroll
\kr       right-scroll
```

The arrow keys and `Esc-(` / `Esc -)` work fine,
as does `Esc-]` for scroll-right,
but `Esc-[` does not work for scroll-left.
Instead, it just shows this in the command line prompt:

```
ESC[
```

Adding this line to `~/.lesskey` functions as a workaround:

```
\e[ left-scroll
```

But why doesn't it work by default?

I have observed this behavior in XFCE4 on Debian stretch as well as Kubuntu 18.04,
as well as a variety of terminal emulators.

```
$ less --version
less 487 (GNU regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2016  Mark Nudelman

less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
For information about the terms of redistribution,
see the file named README in the less distribution.
Homepage: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less
```

I considered filing a bug report,
but [the list of known bugs and feature requests](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html)
suggests that it is a known behavior:

> Enhancement requests
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> Ref number: 175
>
> Implemented in version: 322
>
> Add alternate command for ESC-[.

Is this actually a limitation in `less`,
or is it a quirk in how terminals handle the Escape key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `ESC [` also happens to be the start of the sequence of characters sent by several function keys on some terminals, such as <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>... Those are also bound to some action in `less`.

So when `less` receives a `ESC [`, it's waiting for more (without timing out like some other applications do).

On my terminal `ESC[6~` is <kbd>PageDown</kbd>. If I press <kbd>Alt+[</kbd>, I see `ESC [` like you do. But then I can enter `6` and `~` and that does scroll down.

If you run `TERM=vt100 less` instead of `less`, where the `vt100` terminfo page doesn't have any entry for <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd>... you see `ESC [` works.

If however, you add `\e[ left-scroll` to your `~/.lesskey` (and run `lesskey` to compile it into `~/.less`), you'll notice the `ESC [` works to scroll left, but all the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PageUP</kbd>... stop working, they all scroll left and the extra characters they send cause some beeping.

Looking at the code, it's all about the order the table of commands are processed. The `~/.less` command table is [added last](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/0713eaf8d94ecdd5d4ae48434ee854e0a63d936c/decode.c#L346), but [inserted at the head](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/0713eaf8d94ecdd5d4ae48434ee854e0a63d936c/decode.c#L372), so its entries are processed *before* the builtin ones.

Upon a `ESC [` input, if the entry for `\e[ left-scroll` is found first, it is processed, if the one for `\kD forw-screen` (which on many terminals translates to `\e[6~ forw-screen`) is found first, then [it's only a *prefix* match](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/0713eaf8d94ecdd5d4ae48434ee854e0a63d936c/decode.c#L588), and [`less` waits for more input](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/0713eaf8d94ecdd5d4ae48434ee854e0a63d936c/command.c#L1944).

So, it is kind of a bug. The fix would be to add a timeout. Adding a short timeout would however mean giving up on multi-key commands; a long timeout to give enough time for a user to enter a multi-key command would probably make `ESC [` too unresponsive.

Now, terminals that have <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, etc, would also generally have <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> key which are also bound to `left-scroll`, `right-scroll`, so you may want to use that instead for scrolling.

Comment: Interesting. But if it's on the terminal side, why does binding `\e[ left-scroll` in `lesskey` change things?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver, good point, I missed that part. See the edit for the details.